# Using serial modem with Android

Tags: android, serial-port, ppp

Regards

I'm working on an android project. We are using a tablet that performs a serial RS232 with modem which responds to AT commands.

I send ATD#777 via serial command to the modem. But I can not use the modem network.

- How do I use the modem network in android?
- The android has support for PPP?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows:

- First a script.sh bash was created on linux that contained the pppd command to connect to the satellite modem.
- After the script was created, it was executed in android through the Runtime command
  ex:

> Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "root", "-c",
>   "/path/android_connect.sh", "&> /mnt/sdcard/Download/log.txt"});